# Been offered a job that I want but I want to go backpacking for a couple of months?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, recruitment, human-resources

I have been offered the same job which I used to work at my previous workplace. I'm currently unemployed as I left a different job at the same company because it wasnt for me and I had applied to my old job whilst I was working that position.

Throughout this time I have decided I want to go backpacking, and I already have one month planned for it.

I was told today that I got my old job back which is part time. I told my interviewer/supervisor that I have holidays booked and she said its fine as I just need to tell HR when they approach me about my start date and let them know. I think they will be okay with 1 month if I use as holidays. But I kind of wondered if I could tell them I have planned 6 months off for travelling? I would like some advice on this please. I enjoy the job but I am also passionate about backpacking and I am just stuck in the middle on what is acceptable and reasonable.

Thanks all.

Edit: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I understand that 6 months is very likely to be too long for the employer. 
I wondered if 3 months would sound more reasonable? By the way the job is a very basic cleaning job and its not like a priority job.

Comment: You could just ask and find out? If it's a make or break for you then you already know what you want to do. It's likely you don't get to keep the spot though, especially if they need someone now.

Comment: Only you know what your priorities are. Voting to close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's an acceptable time period for "When can you start?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49086/whats-an-acceptable-time-period-for-when-can-you-start)

Comment: 1 months seems reasonable.  6 would make me look for someone else.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Exactly that.  "Look for a job when your **ready** to go to work".

Answer (score 12):

You can always tell them and ask if it's a problem, but 6 months is a *long* time for anyone to wait. It's very likely that the company will retract the offer and tell you to reapply when you get back.

They will almost certainly need someone to fill in you if you won't be in for 6 months, and at that point they might as well keep that person on. After all; a lot can happen in 6 months, you might be a totally changed person when you come back. (That **is** the goal of 6 months backpacking, is it not?)

Comment: What if I negotiate to 3 months?

Comment: @K.Dee you have to check with the company. Some might be okay with it, some might not.

Comment: Okay, I wondered if I should wait for my job confirmation letter and when HR contact me for me to ask them only then? What do you reckon?

Comment: @K.Dee It is obvious you want to go backpacking instead of taking the job. If that is your priority, go for it. There will be other jobs when you get back. If you are looking for some security for when you return, it doesn't normally work that way. Unless you're a stellar performer that the company cannot live without, they'll find someone else who meets their needs and can start sooner. You're welcome to make backpacking your priority. But it is very likely that it will come at the cost of some job security.

Comment: 3 months is too long too.  @K.Dee do you need a job, or can you afford to take a chance and wait 6 months and see what happens?  If you can go for it....I would be amazed if the company is willing to wait more than a month.

Answer (score 5):

6 months is too long of a period for a job opening. You need to prioritize either the offer or the backpacking. It sounds to me that you want to go backpacking more then this job. If you decide to reject the offer, think of a better reason why. Because if they hire you now or later down the road, no manager would like to know that you can quit over a planned vacation.